# How to delay entire chef recipe

Tags: ruby, shell, chef-infra

Is there anyway I can delay the entire chef recipe running in AWS OpsWorks?

I was trying to execute a sleep command but no success:

```
Chef::Log.info("Delaying chef execution")
execute 'delay' do
  command 'sleep 60'
end
```

What I want to achieve is to delay all the Ruby code in a recipe based on where I make the delay, could be on top, could be in the middle.

EDIT: Complete Chef recipe:

```
Chef::Log.info("stopping service rsyslog")
service 'rsyslog' do
  action :stop
end
Chef::Log.info("configuring private ip addresses for mesos_master templates")
ruby_block "configuring_mesos_master_templates" do
    # Do stuff
end
Chef::Log.info("starting service rsyslog")
service 'rsyslog' do
  action :start
end
Chef::Log.info("restarting service zookeeper")
service 'zookeeper' do
    action :restart
end
Chef::Log.info("restarting service mesos-master")
service 'mesos-master' do
    provider Chef::Provider::Service::Upstart
    action :restart
end
Chef::Log.info("starting service marathon")
service 'marathon' do
    action :start
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing that is fine, or you could use a `ruby_block` resource and Ruby's `sleep()` method. Remember how ordering works though, see https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for an overview of the compile-vs-converge split.

Comment: Actually the code I wrote didn't work, as OpsWorks executes this Chef recipe, everything just ran at the same time.

Comment: Remember that will only sleep at converge time, any Ruby code outside of a ruby_block will run at compile time. If you showed a more complete example it might help.

Comment: Okay, and where in there are you trying to sleep? I'll note for the record that Chef is built around a convergent model/ideology, while the recipe you have there is basically entirely procedural steps and would be better suited to a bash script.

Comment: Also you might be hitting issues related to resource cloning.

Comment: I'm trying to sleep on top of everything

Comment: You probably just want to do a ruby sleep command, `sleep 60`. This will sleep in the compile step before any resources run.

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile Chef (in version 15.5) introduced an own 'chef_sleep resource' for this like described in https://docs.chef.io/resources/chef_sleep/.